# choice_value: Call to a member function getSlug() on a non-object

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony **3.2** , I get this error when using `choice_value` in the formType:

```
Error: Call to a member function getSlug() on a non-object" at D:\wamp\www\my_project\src\AppBundle\Form\Bien\BienType.php line 77
```

---

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Ville;

//...

->add('ville', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Ville',
    'label' => 'Ville',
    'choice_label' => 'nom',
    'placeholder' => 'Ville ',
    'multiple' => false,
    'expanded' => false,
    'choice_value' => function ($ville) {
         /** @var Ville $ville */
         return $ville->getSlug();
    },
))
```

I have the same code in another project with Symfony**3.1** and it works good , does the problem comes from the version of Symfony ?

**EDIT:**

I have tested it with `choice_label` and works fine without any error:

```
'choice_label' => function ($ville) {
    /** @var Ville $ville */
    return $ville->getSlug();
},
```

**EDIT 2:**

Today I have installed Symfony 3.1 and I have tested `choice_value` and I get the same error but no error with the ancien Symfony3.1 installed since some months ago.
I think there are some updates are made on Symfony and causes a bug , is it possible ?

Comment: Can you please show how you create `$ville` before the form?

Comment: @AlvinBunk take a look at this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label

Comment: Yes i know that. In you Entity of Ville, what is the column `name` for the slug? For example, you'll have something like: `@ORM\Column(name="slug_id", type="string")`

Comment: hous, are you sure that when you used the `choice_label` function that it worked with **no** errors? Did you clear your cache using: `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` before you tested? It seems odd that it would work for the label.

Comment: Everything is alright. Yes it works good with choice_label. In fact I have just installed Symfony 3.1 and I test it and I get the same error but no error with the ancien Symfony3.1 installed since some months ago.
I think there are some updates are made on Symfony and causes a bug , is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Since 2.7) the `choice_value` option is used also [to transform the initial data to string value](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/ChoiceToValueTransformer.php#L37), i.e. if you pass a closure function you take control over initial data transformation as well, if it is `null`, you need check it before to call to `$ville->getSlug()`:

```
'choice_value' => function (Ville $ville = null) {
    return $ville ? $ville->getSlug() : '';
},
```

The typehint is good in this case, you has a signature constraint and IDE autocompletation, however you need set default `null` to avoid typehint exception for `null` initial data.

I think it should be documented because devs expect that (like others `choice_*`) it deals with `'choices'` option only.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

Now it works good using like this :

```
'choice_value' => function ($ville) {
                /** @var Ville $ville */
                return $ville ? $ville->getSlug() : '';
            },
```

or like this:

```
'choice_value' => function (Ville $ville = null) {

                return $ville ? $ville->getSlug() : '';
            },
```

[github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21116](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21116#issuecomment-269931090)